# $|Hom_Z(Z_d,C/Z)|=d^2$? where $C$ is complex number.

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is $|Hom_Z(Z_d,C/Z)|$?

It suffices to determine $f(1)=a+bi\in C$. $df(1)=f(d)=0\implies da+dbi\in Z$. Thus I see $a=\frac{u}{d},b=\frac{v}{d},u,v\in Z$ where $0\leq u\leq d-1,0\leq v\leq d-1$. So I got $d^2$ elements.

Book says there are only $d$ elements. However I got $d^2$ elements from above argument.

$\textbf{Q:}$ How many elements are there in $Hom_Z(Z_d,C/Z)$?

$\textbf{Q':}$ Normally one would consider $Q/Z$ or $R/Z$ instead of $C/Z$. Am I wrong here that $C/Z$ gives me $d^2$ elements?

Comment: A map $f:\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z} \to G$ is just an element $g\in G$ of order (dividing) $d$, of which $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}$ has exactly $d$.

Comment: @anomaly Would you mind clarify how to specify the map? What is wrong with my specification of the map? Say what are $d=2$ elements in $Hom_Z(Z_2,C/Z)$? $f(1)=0,1/2,1/2i,1/2+1/2i$. And I count 4 instead 2. Correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: The latter group is $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}$, not $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}[i]$ (even if $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}[i]$ would normally make more sense).

Comment: @anomaly Yes. I think you are right. I should though $C/Z$ as an infinite cylinder with only circle without imaginary parts relevant. The finite order elements only show up in the circle.